# How to sum values are in array using data flow in Azure Data Factory?

Tags: arrays, azure-data-factory

I have a requirement to sum values which are in Array separated by | (Pipe). For Examaple [10|20|30]

Output should be: 60

Requesting you to suggest how to achieve it.

Regards,
Ashok

Comment: Is the array length fixed ? Is the input stream of table type ?

Comment: @JosephXu: Thank you so much for your reply. Input stream is Table, Yes Array length [A]12.

Answer (score 0):

reduce(split(pipeCol, '|'), 0, #acc + toInteger(#item))

Comment: Thank you so much for your reply, As you suggested i have implemented, it is suming up but getting some message along with it, please find the below mentioned msg for your reference. "value":"150.0","type":"LosslessNumber","isLosslessNumber": Could you suggested how to over come it .

Comment: We are achieving the results using above expression. but we getting warning like {"value":"201.55","type":"LosslessNumber","isLosslessNumber":true}
How to avoid it.